# check login via grocery CRUD library

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function customers_management()
{
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_table('customers');
        $crud->columns('customerName','contactLastName','phone','city','country','salesRepEmployeeNumber','postalCode');
        $crud->display_as('salesRepEmployeeNumber','from Employeer')
             ->display_as('customerName','Name')
             ->display_as('contactLastName','Last Name');
        $crud->set_subject('Customer');
        $crud->set_relation('salesRepEmployeeNumber','employees','lastName');

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

here is a function of controller. **What i have to add to make a check for login in it?**

Answer (score 0):

You should look in to other libraries (like [DX_Auth](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/DX_Auth), etc.,.) that takes care of authentication and make a call in the first line of the action.

```
function customers_management() {
    <call the authentication library>
    if (success-login) {
        ... do authenticated operation
    } else {
        ... show him the login page
    }
}
```